# TableView add one row with SAME data when Clicked the button in Cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a custom cell with buttons in the cell. The button works successfully, changing data in Firebase. The Problem is that it ADD one row with same data of the Cell data I clicked.

Here is what happens, I click Follow the User name "Chew", and it adds One row of Chew user, the code run successfully

I test by printing and found out that The ArrayFollowers Add One more value that the table add more row
What is the problem?

Before

[image]

After

[image]

Here my code

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseDatabase

class FollowersVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchBarDelegate{

// MARK: _ DECLARE
    @IBOutlet weak var FollowersTableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var Searchbar: UISearchBar!
    var ref = Database.database().reference()
    var ArrayFollowers = [NSDictionary?]()
    var FilterArrFollowers = [NSDictionary?]()


// MARK: _ OVERVIEW
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let userid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

        Searchbar.delegate = self
         self.FollowersTableView.rowHeight = 67

        //  retrieve the followers users
        ref.child("profile").child(userid!).child("follower").observe(.childAdded, with: {(snapshot) in
            let followerid = snapshot.key
            self.ref.child("profile").child("\(followerid)").observe(.value, with: {(snapshot) in
            let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
                    self.ArrayFollowers.append(value)
                    print("AAAAAAAAA",self.ArrayFollowers)
                    self.FollowersTableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: self.ArrayFollowers.count-1,section: 0)], with: UITableView.RowAnimation.automatic)
            })
        })
    }


// MARK: - TABLEVIEW DATA SOURCE
        func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
            return 1
        }
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            if Searchbar.text != "" {
                       return FilterArrFollowers.count
                   }
            return self.ArrayFollowers.count
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FollowersCell", for: indexPath) as! FollowersTableCell
            let follower : NSDictionary
            let userid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid


            if  Searchbar.text != ""  {
                follower = FilterArrFollowers[indexPath.row]!
             }else{
                follower = ArrayFollowers[indexPath.row]!
            }

            if let profileURL = follower["profilepic"] as? String {
                    cell.Pix.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: profileURL))
                    cell.Pix.circle()
                }
            cell.Username.text = follower["username"] as? String

            self.ref.child("profile").observe(.childAdded, with: {(snapshot) in
            let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
                if value == follower{
                    let followerID = snapshot.ref.key

                    self.ref.child("profile").child(userid!).child("following").observe( .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                        if snapshot.hasChild(followerID!){

                    //  check Following?
                        cell.Followbutton.setTitle("Following", for: .normal)
                        cell.Followbutton.setTitleColor(.lightGray, for: .normal)

                    //  UNFOLLOW action
                        cell.followaction = {
                            cell.Followbutton.setTitle("Follow", for: .normal)
                            cell.Followbutton.setTitleColor(.systemBlue, for: .normal)
                            self.ref.child("profile").child(userid!).child("following").child(followerID!).setValue(nil)
                            self.ref.child("profile").child(followerID!).child("follower").child(userid!).setValue(nil)
                            }
                    }else{

                    //  check NOT Following?
                        cell.Followbutton.setTitle("Follow", for: .normal)
                        cell.Followbutton.setTitleColor(.systemBlue, for: .normal)

                    //  FOLLOW action
                            cell.followaction = {
                                    cell.Followbutton.setTitle("Following", for: .normal)
                                    cell.Followbutton.setTitleColor(.lightGray, for: .normal)
                                    self.ref.child("profile").child(userid!).child("following").updateChildValues([followerID!: true], withCompletionBlock: {(error, ref) in
                                    if error != nil {
                                        print(error!)
                                     return
                                    }
                                    })
                                    self.ref.child("profile").child(followerID!).child("follower").updateChildValues([userid!: true], withCompletionBlock: {(error, ref) in
                                    if error != nil {
                                        print(error!)
                                    return
                                    }
                                    })
                                    }
                        }

                        //  Remove Followers
                        cell.removeaction = {
                            self.ref.child("profile").child(userid!).child("follower").child(followerID!).setValue(nil)
                            self.ref.child("profile").child(followerID!).child("following").child(userid!).setValue(nil)
                            self.ArrayFollowers.remove(at: indexPath.row)
                            self.FollowersTableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
                        }
                                })
                }
            })
        return cell
        }


// MARK: - SEARCH FUNCTION
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        filteredContent(searchText: self.Searchbar.text!)
    }
    func filteredContent(searchText: String){
        self.FilterArrFollowers = self.ArrayFollowers.filter{ user in
            let username = user!["username"] as? String
                    return(username?.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()))!
        }
        FollowersTableView.reloadData()
    }
}


// MARK: _ CELL CLASS
class FollowersTableCell: UITableViewCell{

    var followaction : (() -> ()) = {}
    var removeaction : (() -> ()) = {}

    @IBOutlet weak var Pix: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var Username: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var Followbutton: UIButton!


    @IBAction func FollowButton(_ sender: Any) {
        followaction()
    }
    @IBAction func removebutton(_ sender: Any) {
        removeaction()
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `NSDictionary` instead of `Dictionary`? Variable names should start with lowercase letter

Comment: @iOSDev I think it doesnt matter much. do you suggest that I should use Dictionary?

Comment: That is not related to your issue but it is better to use

Comment: @iOSDev Thanx, but did you see any problem there?

Answer (score 0):

Just before the get data is from Firebase, you should remove ArrayFlower.

```
ArrayFlowers.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
```

Comment: Get error: Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you will not check the follower is Already exist in ArrayFollowers. So, You should check that like

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let userid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

    Searchbar.delegate = self
     self.FollowersTableView.rowHeight = 67

    //  retrieve the followers users
    ref.child("profile").child(userid!).child("follower").observe(.childAdded, with: {(snapshot) in
        let followerid = snapshot.key
        self.ref.child("profile").child("\(followerid)").observe(.value, with: {(snapshot) in
        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
                if !self.ArrayFollowers.contains(value)
                {
                   self.ArrayFollowers.append(value)
                }
                //Here check that the follower is not in array then add otherwise not
                print("AAAAAAAAA",self.ArrayFollowers)
                self.FollowersTableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: self.ArrayFollowers.count-1,section: 0)], with: UITableView.RowAnimation.automatic)
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: still not working out, the code still add One same value in

Answer (score 0):

**update answer**

Finally, I found out the small mistake.  View Did Load()

```
//  retrieve the followers users
        ref.child("profile").child(userid!).child("follower").observe(.childAdded, with: {(snapshot) in
            let followerid = snapshot.key
            self.ref.child("profile").child("\(followerid)").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snapshot) in
            let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
```